# Python multiprocessing logger is logging to both file and console for both debug and info

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing

I had a script written using threading that I am migrating to multiprocessing.  Along with this, I have to change how logging works.  I am trying to do a quick test with QueueHandlers to make sure it works how it works with threading but I'm having an issue with both info and debug messages appearing on the screen and in the file.

The desired behavior is to have debug messages write only to the file and info messages write to both screen and file.  When I run the following code, it writes both messages to both locations.  Any ideas why this is happening?

```
from logging.handlers import QueueListener, QueueHandler
import logging
import os
import multiprocessing
import sys

def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue(-1)
    formatter = "%(asctime)s - [%(levelname)s] - %(name)s - (%(filename)s).%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s"
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler("b.log")
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(formatter))

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    console_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(formatter))

    queue_listener = QueueListener(queue, file_handler, console_handler)
    queue_listener.start()

    main_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    main_logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(queue))
    main_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    main_logger.info("info - log to console and disk")
    main_logger.debug("debug - log to disk only")
    queue_listener.stop()
```

This is what I get on the screen...both messages also appear in the file.

```
2021-08-05 11:26:11,330 - [INFO] - __main__ - (mp_logging.py).main(32) - info - log to console and disk
2021-08-05 11:26:11,330 - [DEBUG] - __main__ - (mp_logging.py).main(33) - debug - log to disk only
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out....  needed to add respect_handler_level=True to the QueueListener.

```
queue_listener = QueueListener(
    logger_queue,
    file_handler,
    console_handler,
    respect_handler_level=True
)
```